# Rails acts_as_taggable_on Tag Link Filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, link-to, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a list of 'notes', and each note has some tags via acts_as_taggable_on. It's a great plugin, and the tags are working wonderfully.

What would be the best way to filter this list of notes by the tag that is clicked on?

Example:

```
<% @notes.each do |note| %>
  <%= note.content %>

  <% note.tag_list.each do |tag| %>
    <%= link_to tag, '#', :class => "tag" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What should I replace the '#' with in order to change or scope out @notes? Not too familiar with this.

EDIt: I want something just like StackOverFlow actually, how would I add parameters to the URL based on the link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I figured it out. Was just having an off-moment.

I can create a named route like:

```
match 'tags/:tag' => 'controller#index', :as => 'tag'
```

And that way I can get the parameter I need.